# Cannot generate an array of results for my numerical method

Tags: performance-tuning, output-formatting, formatting, numerical-value, numeric-array

I want to apply the following scheme:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\psi_{i, j+1} &=-\psi_{i, j-1}+\left(\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta r_*}\right)^2\left(\psi_{i+1, j}+\psi_{i-1, j}\right) \\
&+\left(2-2\left(\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta r_*}\right)^2-v_i \Delta t^2\right) \psi_{i, j} \\
v_i &=v\left(r_*\right)=\frac{f(r)}{r} \frac{d f}{d r}+\frac{f(r) l(l+1)}{o^2} / \cdot r \rightarrow r_* \\
r_* &=r+(8+b) \ln |r-8-b| \\
f(r) &=1-\frac{8+b}{r}
\end{aligned}$$

$r_{*}=i*dr$, $dr=.01$, $t=j*dt$, $dt=.1$.

The code I have written is as follows:

```
    rn = r /. Solve[r + R*Log[r - R] - rs == 0, r][[1]]
    
    R = 8 + b
    
    F = 1 - (R/r)
    
    D[F, r]
    
    Veff[rs_, b_, l_] = (F/r)*D[F, r] + (F/r^2)*l*(1 + l) /. r -> rn
    Ga[i_, j_, dr_, dt_, b_, l_] := (
      Ga[i, 0, dr, dt, b, l] = Exp[-(i*dr - 10)^2/18];
      Ga[i, -1, dr, dt, b, l] = 0;
      Do[Ga[i, k + 1, dr, dt, b, 
         l] = -Ga[i, k - 1, dr, dt, b, 
           l] + (dt/dr)^2*(Ga[i + 1, k, dr, dt, b, l] + 
            Ga[i - 1, k, dr, dt, b, l]) + (2 - 2*(dt/dr)^2 - 
            N[Veff[i*dr, b, l]])*Ga[i, k, dr, dt, b, l];
       Ga[i + 1, k + 1, dr, dt, b, 
         l] = -Ga[i + 1, k - 1, dr, dt, b, 
           l] + (dt/dr)^2*(Ga[i + 2, k, dr, dt, b, l] + 
            Ga[i, k, dr, dt, b, l]) + (2 - 2*(dt/dr)^2 - 
            N[Veff[(i + 1)*dr, b, l]])*Ga[i + 1, k, dr, dt, b, l];
       Ga[i - 1, k + 1, dr, dt, b, 
         l] = -Ga[i - 1, k - 1, dr, dt, b, 
           l] + (dt/dr)^2*(Ga[i, k, dr, dt, b, l] + 
            Ga[i - 2, k, dr, dt, b, l]) + (2 - 2*(dt/dr)^2 - 
            N[Veff[(i - 1)*dr, b, l]])*Ga[i - 1, k, dr, dt, b, l], {k, 0, 
        j}];
      Print[Ga[i, j, dr, dt, b, l]])
```

I want to `ListPlot` the generated data for `t=0` to `t=400`. I am not getting any numerical output just lots of errors. Can someone help me please? Thanks.

Comment: With MMA version 13.1 Windows 10, I do only get a warning that inverse functions are being used, but I get a solution

Comment: I have MMA version 12.0. Can you generate array for t from 0 to 400?@DanielHuber

Comment: Array of Ga[..]?But this is not a function of t. And you did not specify  b and rs.

Comment: In the body I have mentioned t= j*dt where dt=.1. b=1 and rs=0. There is one more variable l=0.

Comment: And what about "i"?

Comment: It is 0@DanielHuber

Comment: I get the same number for all elements.